# In the following code I periodically get "500" as a value. How do I fix this?

Tags: c++

I get 0 and 5000 randomly (which is how I wanted it to work, a 30% chance to receive 5000) however I also get 500 which I assume is due to the fact that it's not running the function at all? I'm not really sure, I'm very new to coding.

```
int gamble2 (int money){
    srand(time(0));
    int rand();
    if (rand() % 100 >= 70){
        money += 4500;
    }
    else if (rand() % 100 < 70){
        money -= 500;
    }
    return money;
}

main()
{
    int startingmoney = 500;
    int money = startingmoney;
    int objective = 100000;
    cout << gamble2(money) << endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the line `int rand();` is doing? That should've thrown some kind of warning or error. You should always compile with all warnings turned on and pay attention to them.

Comment: You are rolling *twice* in your function. First result you check if it's greater than 70, second if it's less. You should save result of `rand()` call in a variable and check that variable or remove `else if` and replace it with `else`.

Comment: Unrelated, `srand(time(0));` does *not* belong in that function if it is *ever* to be invoked more than once. It should be invoked near/at the top of `main` and never done again for the life of the process.

Comment: That's... not exactly a right duplicate. It's a part of the problem, but not the main one.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen do you believe it's actually worth reopening?